# Server crashes when systemd is updated

Tags: server, 20.04, systemd, crash

Haven't found a similar issue in the forums, but this problem happens on my virtual servers every time systemd needs to be updated: the (physical) server crashes, and all virtual machines on it become of course unavailable.

It began after upgrading the virtual machines from Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (never happened before). It happened last week again, and the last lines before crash read:

```
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf ...
```

Yesterday, not only the server, but also the Chassis crashed. We had to go on site to restart.

Any clue? As the servers are in production, I don't want to make too many tests...

Thanks!
Greg

Comment: Look at the logs. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Took me time :-) A look at what was in the logs didn't expained me much. I think I'll try a new crash to know more. Funny thing: an update with systemd on 18.04 takes at most 50% CPU for a very short time, as an update with systemd on 20.04 takes 100% CPU...

Comment: Did you find a solution? It also happens to my VM.

Comment: See my answer below :)

Comment: Thanks @Greg, didn't help in my case but it could be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to mark the problem solved: we had to update the drivers of the infrastructure (Dell VRTX and PowerEdge), and the problem disappeared. Hope this helps